# How can I convert from Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> to Func<TSource, bool> condition

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I am trying to convert from

```
x => x.SomeProperty
```

to

```
x => x.SomeProperty is ISomeInterface
```

In a method that fits the following signature:

```
Func<TSource, bool> Convert(Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> source);
```

Where SomeProperty might be a collection or a single object. Can anyone help?

I'm finding it difficult to work out what kind of expressions these are. I think that the first one is a MemberExpression and the second is a UnaryExpression.

I'd be happy to move the

```
x.SomeProperty is ISomeInterface
```

logic into a method if that would make things easier.

```
bool IsSomeInterface(object obj)
{
  return obj is ISomeInterface;
}
```

Any pointers or tutorials on how to put this stuff together would be appreciated. I always seem to struggle with Expression trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `Expression.TypeIs(...)`. Try this:

```
    Func<TSource, bool> Convert<TSource, TSourceMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> source)
    {
        return (Func<TSource, bool>)(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(Expression.TypeIs(source.Body, typeof(ISomeInterface)), source.Parameters).Compile());
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to use an index on source.parameters

Comment: @johnny5 Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: Plus one for the quick response.  This should be marked as the right answer

Comment: @kanders84152 thank you very much. Can you recommend a good place to start leaning this stuff? I only brush against it now and again and always seem to struggle.

Comment: @Adam I'm sure there are decent resources out there, but I've never read them. To be honest, I had no idea there was an `Expression.TypeIs(...)` function until this question. I just fed `x => x.SomeProperty is ISomeInterface` into an expression and played around with the things I got out. So, I guess I'd say that the best place to learn it is to play around with it and experiment. It's amazing how much one can learn from just monkeying around with things.